# Want available booking time from table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables in which i have timings

1st table

```
id    time

 1.     9:00
 2.     10:00
 3.     11:00
 4.     12:00
 5.     01:00
 6.     02:00
 7.     03:00
```

2nd table is my booking table in which users made appointment

```
id    start_time end_time


 1.     9:00      10:00
 2.     10:00     12:00
 3.     02:00     03:00
```

I want to get the available timings that are left in 2nd table suppose the timing from 12:00 to 01:00 is free so i want that my query will select available timings I need to use MySQL query for that and please tell me a query to do it as i do not have any idea what query i can use to get available timings. Your help will be highly appreciated. 
Thank you

Comment: Just to be clear, appointments cannot be made overnight? Like start_time 23:00 end_time= 1:00?

Comment: [available booking MySQL (144 results)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=available+booking+MySQL) most likely you will find answers in already existing questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `appointment`;
CREATE TABLE  `appointment` (
  `ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Start` datetime NOT NULL,
  `End` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

insert into appointment (`Start`,`End`) values ('2019-01-18 09:00:00','2019-01-18 10:00:00'),('2019-01-18 10:00:00','2019-01-18 12:00:00'),('2019-01-18 14:00:00','2019-01-18 15:00:00');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mhc_common`.`schedule`;
CREATE TABLE  `mhc_common`.`schedule` (
  `ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Time` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

insert into schedule (`Time`) values ('2019-01-18 09:00:00'),('2019-01-18 10:00:00'),('2019-01-18 11:00:00'),('2019-01-18 12:00:00'),('2019-01-18 13:00:00'),('2019-01-18 14:00:00'),('2019-01-18 15:00:00'),('2019-01-18 16:00:00');
```

Try This To return the Times Available

```
Select ID
     , s.Time 
  From Schedule s 
  Left 
  Join
     ( SELECT Time
            , if((`Time` >= `Start` and `Time` < `End`),'N','Y') NA 
         FROM appointment a
            , schedule b 
       Having NA = 'N'
     ) a
    On a.Time = s.Time
 Where `NA` is Null;
```